# parser: parsing formulas in template files

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

I  will first describe the problem and then what I currently look at, in terms of libraries.

In my application, we have a set of variables that are always available. For example: TOTAL_ITEMS, PRICE, CONTRACTS, ETC (we have around 15 of them). A clients of the application  would like to have certain calculations performed and displayed, using those variables. Up until now,  I have been constantly adding those calculations to the app. It's pain in the butt, and I would like to  make it more generic by way of creating a template, where the user can specify a set of formulas that the application will  parse and calculate.

Here is one case:

```
total_cost = CONTRACTS*PRICE*TOTAL_ITEMS
```

So, want to do something like that for the user to define in the template file:

`total_cost = CONTRACTS*PRICE*TOTAL_ITEMS`  and some meta-date, like screen to display it on. Hence they will be specifying the formula with a screen. And the file will contain many formulas of this nature.

Right now, I am looking at two libraies: [Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/spirit/classic/index.html) and [matheval](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matheval)

Would anyone make recommendations  what's better for this task, as well as references, examples, links?

Please let me know if the question is unclear, and I will try to further clarify it .

Thanks,

Sasha

Comment: It looks like matheval was written in Euphoria... is that a problem for your use-case?

Comment: What is the problem with that?

Comment: I guess the main problem is that you need Euphoria ! :-)

Comment: Isn't just a cpp binary?  it works for us, for other apps, on AS3..

Comment: I guess Euphoria can be compiled to C and exported as C functions in a DLL so that is probably what you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a fixed number of variables it may be a bit overkill to invoke a parser.  Though Spirit is cool and I've been wanting to use it in a project.

I would probably just tokenize the string, make a map of your variables keyed by name (assuming all your variables are ints):

```
map<const char*,int*> vars;
vars["CONTRACTS"] = &contracts;
...
```

Then use a simple postfix calculator function to do the actual math.

Edit:

Looking at MathEval, it seems to do exactly what you want; set variables and evaluate mathematical functions using those variables.  I'm not sure why you would want to create a solution at the level of a syntax parser.  Do you have any requirements that MathEval does not fulfill?

Comment: well, it could be a bit tricky as I have to use many different operators (- + * /)- formula can go use 30 constants, some might repeated.

Comment: Both libraries fulfill my requirements,  as far as I can tell ...the question is extensibility and complexity  with  using one over the other...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it shouldn't be too hard to generate a simple parser using [yacc](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/) and [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) and integrate it into your code.

Comment: Then why don't go for Spirit? Results in less dependencies on external tools (I consider Spirit less external than yacc and friends)

Comment: In the context of spirit vs. yacc, then I would certainly go for boost. However, I also see that matheval is lightweight as well as easier to use for a less complicated grammar. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about matheval, but boost::spirit can do that for you pretty efficiently : see [there](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/spirit/classic/doc/trees.html).

If you're into template metaprogramming, you may want to have a look into [Boost::Proto](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/proto.html), but it **will** take some time to get started using it.